# .change in jQuery is not giving me the results i need for a select

Tags: jquery

Here is my html

```
<select class="selecturl">
 <optgroup label="Fruit">

  <option value="/something/167/remote">Apple</option>

  <option selected="" value="/something/168/remote">Oranges</option>

  <option value="/something/169/remote">Bananas</option>

  <option value="/something/170/remote">Carots</option>

 </optgroup>
</select>
```

And here is my jQuery

```
$('.selecturl').change(function() {
      console.log(this);
```

I have no idea how to get the string "Apple" or anything that is selected

Comment: Thank you for bringing up `<optgroup>`! Though it sounds stupid, I couldn't think of this element for the life of me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the selected option, or [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) of the [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) option if you want the text, like this:

```
$('.selecturl').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val()); //gets the value
  console.log($(this).find(':selected').text()); //gets the text
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/dvcyb/).